# How to extend disk size /dev/sda and /boot,/boot in Linux?

Tags: filesystems

```
sda      8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0  300M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda3   8:3    0 17.7G  0 part /
```

Comment: Good questions aren't just a dump of data; they provide some context and explanation. Ideally they'll include elements of your own attempts and research so that we don't duplicate your own effort

Comment: Best question ever!

Answer (score 0):

Use `gparted`; it has a tool to resize. 
You will have to shrink another partition, unless you have free space elsewhere.